# Is there a way to make JPA entity non-persistent while it passing a valid entity validation?

Tags: jpa, entity

**Is there a way to make JPA entity non-persistent while it passing a valid entity validation?**

I want an abstract class to work as an valid entity which will be having relationship with other entities?

Comment: An abstract class won't work as an valid entity - as an abstract class can't have any instances...

Comment: Not sure where you're getting at... If you have an object managed by an entity manager, and you want it to be un-managed (aka. transient), then call `entityManager.detach(entity)`. To make it managed later you can call `entityManager.merge(entity)` again.